# What is wrong with my haworthia?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, succulents, sunlight

I took over somebody's Haworthia plant a while ago, and kept watering it at the same frequency (once a week), but this is how it looks like after two months:

[image: Haworthia]

The symptoms are that turn yellow and then brown, and might even fall of, starting from the lower end of the branch. According to the previous owner, this behavior seems to indicate that it is too wet, but the soil is dry to very dry.

The plant is now exposed to (direct) sun for longer periods than in the old location - could it be a kind of sunburn?